Download file from apex
I have requirement in which on clicking filename , I would be able to download it from apex app. I am able to display it but it is not getting downloaded.
I am using below code to display and download the file. It is displaying correct data , mime_type value is correct - text/csv.
DECLARE
    l_blob      BLOB;
    l_length    NUMBER;
    l_mime_type VARCHAR2(50);
    l_file_name VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    -- Retrieve file details from the database
    SELECT filecontent, filetype, filename
      INTO l_blob, l_mime_type, l_file_name
      FROM file_ingestion
     WHERE file_id =:P0_ID; -- Use the correct page item

    -- Set the response headers for file download
    owa_util.mime_header(l_mime_type, FALSE); -- Set MIME type
    --htp.p('Content-Length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob)); -- Set file size
    htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || l_file_name || '"'); -- Set filename and prompt download
    owa_util.http_header_close;


    -- Output the file content
    wpg_docload.download_file(l_blob);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        htp.p('An error occurred: ' || SQLERRM);

END;

More context -
I have an apex interactive report which displays all the files stored in file ingestion table. This report has a link attribute set on filename which will be redirecting it to the another page in application called - download and will take p0-id as file id which is the unique key of the table as well. Now in download page , in region I am selecting type as dynamic content and then the mentioned pl/SQL code.

do you get an error? Did you check if your browser block the downloads? Please provide more details and also check new API (https://lmoreaux.hashnode.dev/how-to-easily-download-files-in-oracle-apex-241)

no error, new api is not working for me.
the output on browser looks like
Number,Elapsed,Statement,Feedback,Rows 1,0.03,DECLARE l_dept_id NUMBER; BEGIN l_dept_id := :P2_CAP,Statement processed.,1

No need to write a page process for this. Check the API APEX_UTIL.GET_BLOG_FILE_SRC to generate a link that downloads the file. For an example (report), install the sample app "Sample File Upload and Download" from the Gallery.


thanks for answer, but this api seems confusing what I need to give as first parameter. SELECT file_id, filename,CASE WHEN NVL(dbms_lob.getlength(filecontent),0) = 0
THEN NULL
ELSE CASE WHEN filetype like 'image%'
THEN ''
ELSE
'Download'
end
END new_img
FROM compute_file_ingestion WHERE
file_id =14490912; O/P 14490912 results.csv Download no link generated.

Did you install the sample app as I suggested ? What were your findings ? I'm unable to provide more help with the limited information in the post. Is this a report ? A form ? Please update your question with as much relevant detail as possible.

No I have not installed anything, I can only find documentation link. I have updated the question with context.

Start with installing that sample app - that is meant as documentation. It should be in the gallery. It has a report with links to files that can be downloaded. Investigate it and try to use the solution in that app for your use case. Update your question if you still have issues.
